# How to properly delete a ManyToOne relationship from Parent in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to understand how to properly delete a many to one relationship.

Let's suppose I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String lastname;
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "badge")
public class Badge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String code;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "badge_id")
    private User user;
    
}
```

Now these two entites have different controllers and services. I can delete a badge in the BadgeService and  delete a user in its service.

```
@Service
public class BadgeService {

    @Autowired
    BadgeRepository badgeRepository;
    
    public void delete(int id) {
        badgeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public void delete(int id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that if I delete a badge everthing works but If I delete a User a got an error due to the FK.

To solve the problem I came up with 2 ways but I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this kind of problem:

### First Way

I simply create a method in the badge repository to delete all badges related to the specific user.

```
public interface BadgeRepository extends CrudRepository<Badge, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE Badge b WHERE b.user.id = :userId")
    public void deleteByUserId(@Param("userId") int userId);

}
```

Then I create a method in the badge service.

```
@Service
public class BadgeService {

    @Autowired
    BadgeRepository badgeRepository;

    public void delete(int id) {
        badgeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteByUserId(int userId) {
        badgeRepository.deleteByUserId(userId);
    }

}
```

And last I simply autowire badge service in user service and call the method in the user delete.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    BadgeService badgeService;
    
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        badgeService.deleteByUserId(id);
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

#### Cons:

If I have multiple relationships with the User entity, I will end up autowiring a lot of services in the user service and that is bad.

### Second Way

Instead of having an unidirectional relationship I create a bidirectional relationship between User and Badge.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Badge> badges = new ArrayList<Badge>();

}
```

And when I delete a user, the cascade or simplying removing the badge from the colletion will delete all the related badges.

#### Cons:

1. Extra Query
2. If the collection is too big the app performances will decrease

That being said, what would you suggest? first or second approach? Maybe there is a better approach to handle this problem?

Thank you all.

Comment: What makes you think that there is an extra query with the second approach?

Comment: If I use a bidirectional relationship I need to keep synchronized both sides, so when I insert a badge I should call the method userService.addBadge which will fetch the whole collection.

Comment: You 'should' but don't have to. The owning side of the relationship controls the FK, so it is the only side you must update. The other is recommended, but isn't mandatory; If you must maintain it, do so. If you can't, just figure out the effects and verify you can live with it. Ie the relationship will be stale if you don't maintain it, cache that parent for any length of time - non-issues if you never fetch the relationship.

Comment: To avoid performance issues on delete, let the database do the delete for you with the ON DELETE CASCADE option. EclipseLInk has an annotation (see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cascadeondelete.htm ) so it avoids the query and Hibernate must have something similar. The overhead involved should determine which you go with, but only testing can tell you which is really better for your application. I've gone with variations of all 3 approaches for various reasons in the same project - none are perfect one fits all type solutions.

Comment: @Chris If I have to create a bidirectional relationship just to use the cascade maybe it's better to use the db cascade which is faster. As you said using the db cascade I would avoid performance issues.

Comment: If you don't need the reference from user->badge don't map it. I've found the opposite of your "I will end up autowiring a lot of services in the user service and that is bad." to be true. It has always been beneficial in my projects that the User handling knows about all resources tied to a User. Some of those maybe just database data and there is no problem letting JPA or the DB clear them, others may exist in other places and need different mechanisms to get cleaned up. Some future dev may need to know which resources are cleared when users are and the many different paths to delete badges.

Comment: There isn't a perfect way to handle this. If I use bidirectional relationship I will end up fetching a lot of data. If I don't sync the relationship I cannot use the cache but at least I don't have to fetch the relationship and cascade works. If I use the db cascade I resolve the performance issue but then JPA cannot be notified about the changes and future dev may have hard time to understand what happens when user gets deleted. To be honest I would stick to db cascade, less code and better perfomance but it  certainly has its downsides.

Comment: @Chris I could probably also implement a bidirectional mapping without syncing and not implementing caching. This would make it clear what happens when a user is deleted. I just cannot decide what's better.

Comment: You do not need to ever fetch any data with a bidirectional relationship. That is what lazy (and JSONIgnore and other annotations) are for. You fetch it only if you need it, and it shows the logical mapping of the data in the model. There are other ways to do this, hundreds if you spend the time looking. JPA picked this approach because it seems most commonly used and fits most use cases. I'm not sure what synching you mean (setting both sides?). Other providers (EclipseLink) can allow you to add to a lazy collection without fetching it. Pick the tradeoffs that suite your apps needs

Answer (score 0):

By handling the badge deletion in user service, you make it clear what should happen at user deletion. Now anyone who deletes an user will delete also its relations (you can think about that as a side effect). So the first way is the best that you can do.

Just make sure to not try to delete users from badge service. That would mean circular dependency and would create confusion about who is the owner of the relation.

Answer (score 0):

First approach looks good in this scenario. To keep UserService clean you can create a PreRemove lisener on User entity which will remove all associations before user deletion, and this will help to keep UserService clean.
The next thing to handle here, you need to change CASCADE

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListener(UderDeletionListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Badge> badges = new ArrayList<Badge>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "badge")
public class Badge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String code;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "badge_id")
    private User user;
    
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UderDeletionListener {
  private final BadgeRepository badgeRepo;

  @PreRemove
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void onDeletion(final User user) {
   badgeRepo.deleteByUserId(user.getId());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Scenario its better to archive your badge rather then direct delete.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "badge")
public class Badge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String code;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "badge_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "archived")
    private boolean archived;

}
```

Because the user entity may be associated with some other entities also.

So instead of delete you may mark batch entity as archived.

Or you can try the following...First Update the relation of batch user ,set it to null and then delete the badge.

```
@Service
public class BadgeService {

    @Autowired
    BadgeRepository badgeRepository;
    
    public void updateBadgeUser(int id) {
        Badge badge = findBadgeById(id);
        badge.setUser(null);
    }

    public void deleteBadge(int id) {
        
       badgeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

But i would suggest you to follow the archive policy.